# Handliing validation erros in a nested form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am building a nested form (LiveView) and would like to validate the nested association. However, even though the nested association returns an error in the changeset, when the changeset is used in the Form, the errors are not picked up. I have attached a dump of the form below and I am not sure how to get the errors to show up on the changeset.

I have a table a transactions table that references itself (e.g., something like friends splitting their bills). I am able to do all the normal happy path operations

```
schema "transactions" do
    field :date, :date
    field :amount, :float
    field :has_splits, :boolean, default: false

    field :temp_id, :string, virtual: true
    field :delete, :boolean, virtual: true

    belongs_to :parent_transaction, Transactions, foreign_key: :parent_transaction_id

    has_many :child_transactions, Transactions, foreign_key: :parent_transaction_id
end
```

When there is an error in one of the children, the changeset shows an error (does not save to the table as expected) but the form never picks up the error.

I am casting the association as follows:

```
  def changeset(transactions, attrs) do
    transactions
    |> cast(attrs, @params)
    |> cast_assoc(:child_transactions)
    |> validate_required([:amount, :date])
  end
```

The form snippet looks like:

```
<.form let={ f } for={ @changeset } phx-change="validate" phx-target={ @myself } phx-submit="save">
 <%= inputs_for f, :child_transactions, fn v -> %>
 <%= hidden_input v, :parent_transaction_id %>
   <%= label v, :amount, class: "label"%>
   <div>
    <%= text_input v, :amount, class: "input" %>
    <%= error_tag v, :amount %>
   </div>
  
   ....
```

However, when I enter a bad value for amount, the error never gets reflected on the UI. So I inspected the form when there is an error and I see this:

```
%Phoenix.HTML.Form{
  action: nil,
  data: %App.Transaction.Transactions{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "transactions">,
    amount: nil,
    child_transactions: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :child_transactions is not loaded>,
    date: nil,
    delete: nil,
    has_splits: false,
    id: nil,
    inserted_at: nil,
    parent_id: nil,
    parent_transaction: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :parent_transaction is not loaded>,
    temp_id: "1476de26-544f-4640-8f8e-7e68882a84c1",
    updated_at: nil,
  },
  errors: [],
  hidden: [],
  id: "transactions_child_transactions_0",
  impl: Phoenix.HTML.FormData.Ecto.Changeset,
  index: 0,
  name: "transactions[child_transactions][0]",
  options: [],
  params: %{
    "amount" => "a",
    "date" => ~D[2020-04-13],
    "parent_transaction_id" => "05f8d1c9-2ed2-4994-a7fb-56c0d334c250",
    "temp_id" => "1476de26-544f-4640-8f8e-7e68882a84c1",
  },
  source: #Ecto.Changeset<
    action: nil,
    changes: %{
      date: ~D[2020-04-13],
      effective_date: ~D[2020-04-13],
    },
    errors: [amount: {"is invalid", [type: :float, validation: :cast]}],
    data: #App.Transaction.Transactions<>,
    valid?: false
  >
}
```

The `source` field says the changeset is invalid but somehow the `errors` field has `[]` so we are not able to show the error via `error_tag`.

Is there something I need to be doing in `cast_assoc` so this bubbles up to the form?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the name of the association `:child_transactions` or `:children_transactions`? You use both.

Comment: @PeacefulJames Sorry `child_transactions`. It was initially `children_` and I renamed but I forgot to update it here as I was editing things to keep the example small.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone gets here because of the same issue:

I ran into the same situation and managed to fix it setting the `:action` in the parent changeset:

```
changeset = 
  transactions
  |> Transactions.changeset(attrs)
  |> Map.put(:action, :validate)
```

Some source about it: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#form_for/4-a-note-on-errors